# List of condition variables for WiX custom actions?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I'm grappling with a few issues as a first time WiX user.

When it comes to `CustomAction`'s, I've seen a few examples of people putting conditional statements in the element body - things like '`Installed`', '`REINSTALL`' and '`REMOVE`', to determine whether or not they are executed.

Where are these variables defined, and does there exist a complete list of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A description about properties is given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370889.aspx) and a list of variables defined by MSI itself is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx). You are able to use other properties as well (WiX defines a lot of them - for example there is [a list](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) of .NET related properties).

Comment: Thanks, really great answer. Raises another few questions - is it possible to see the output of these variables in a cmd prompt or something? Also, I noticed when a .MSI process is started, it can take arguments. Is there a property that exposes these?

Comment: 1. you may use the log output to view the properties contents (/l*v) 2. you can write `msiexec ... PROPERTY=value`. This command creates a property named `PROPERTY`